# SQL : if value is between 1 and 10000 then inserted otherwise kept as null

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to insert record in sql table. Condition is
if value is between 1 to 10000 then inserted otherwise kept as null (not "").

What can I do while creating table if i want these two conditions to apply?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, if you're inserting, there's no value to keep as null. Do you mean that the field of the inserted row should be set to null if outside the range?

Comment: Are you inserting from one table to another and altering the new tables data on the fly?  Can you show some code you've attempted?

Comment: See answer below. Try to implement something then ask for further help as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can be obtained through the use of a an SQL trigger and database stored procedure.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx